# How to check if/how often my process is preempted by the kernel?

Tags: linux, scheduling, real-time

For the purpose of profiling a program I would like to run it uninterrupted on one CPU.
To do this I use a combination of `taskset` and `chrt`:

```
# taskset -c 1 chrt -f 99 ./my_program
```

Now my question is if there is a tool that lets me check if/how often the process is nevertheless interrupted by context switches to the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`perf`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page); for example,

```
perf stat -e context-switches,cpl_cycles.ring0,cpl_cycles.ring123 your_command
```

will produce a summary similar to

```
 Performance counter stats for 'your_command':

                 1      context-switches                                            
        11,890,096      cpl_cycles.ring0                                            
         9,980,265      cpl_cycles.ring123                                          

       0.011218937 seconds time elapsed

       0.007533000 seconds user
       0.003766000 seconds sys
```

which shows that there was one context switch (to another process, not the kernel) during `your_command`’s execution, and the CPU spent 54% of its time running kernel code.

Ensuring that a given process gets as much of the CPU’s attention as possible can get quite complicated. [Victor Stinner’s benchmark setup documentation](https://vstinner.readthedocs.io/benchmark.html) provides a good overview of the problems, and techniques to mitigate them; his write-up is focused on benchmarking but much of it is applicable in other circumstances.